# @fontface from a Mac font

Tags: macos, fonts, font-face

I received a font file from a Mac designer called ._Birdman, and I would like to know how can I convert it to a TTF font to create a fontface. The problem is that I have downloaded the ttf birdman font, but I have no tildes or special characters on it.

The designer shows me that he has special character on his Mac. Is there any way to convert it?

Comment: Not programming related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a program called CrossFont that does the trick.